# How to calculate cpu usage in % with the raw CPU ticks in SNMP

Tags: cpu, monitoring, snmp

I was wondering how to calculate the percentage of CPU usage using the raw values obtained via these oids:

- UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawIdle.0
- UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser.0
- UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawSystem.0

I looked in the net-snmp documentation but I had a lot of trouble understanding how to proceed and calculate the percentage with these values.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/441897/how-to-calculate-cpu-based-on-raw-cpu-ticks-in-snmp You checked the docs but not google?